# Como fazer que um objeto na ListView tenha uma posição absoluta?

Tags: java, android, array, listview

Tenho uma listView com vários itens, tenho também logo a cima um searchView para realizar um filtro nesses itens, sendo eles "clicáveis", iniciando outra Activity.

O problema é que a numeração dos itens da lisView mudam de acordo com o que pesquiso na searchView. Ou seja não consigo setar uma Activity para cada item da listView de forma que os itens da Array tenham uma posição absoluta.Alguma luz?

Aqui vai o código em questão.

```
ListView lv;
    SearchView sv;
    String[] teams={"Absolutismo",
            "Agentes de Relevo",
            "Alelobiose",
            "Alta Idade Média",
            "América",


    };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_pesquisa);
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        sv=(SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,teams);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                int itemPosition = position;

                // ListView Clicked item value
                String  itemValue = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);

                // Show Alert
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                switch( position )
                {
                    case 0:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(telaPesquisa.this, historiaAbsolutismo.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity);
                        break;
                    case 1:  Intent newActivityy = new Intent(telaPesquisa.this, geografiaAgentesFormadoresDeRelevo.class);
                        startActivity(newActivityy);
                        break;
                    case 2:  Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(telaPesquisa.this, biologiaAlelobioses.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity2);
                        break;
                    case 3:  Intent newActivity3 = new Intent(telaPesquisa.this, historiaAltaIdadeMedia.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity3);
                        break;
                    case 4:  Intent newActivity4 = new Intent(telaPesquisa.this, geografiaAmerica.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity4);
                        break;
                }

            }
        });




             sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(text);
                return false;
            }
        });





    }

}
```

[[image: Aqui a "position" está em 0 para o item Absolutismo]Aqui a "position" está em 0 para o item Absolutismo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV3bj.jpg)

[[image: Aqui a "position" está no mesmo 0 para outro item]Aqui a "position" está no mesmo 0 para outro item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz97V.jpg)

[[image: Lista em questão]Lista em questão](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXwdN.jpg)

Comment: Não consegui me arrumar com as formatações do código no fórum, desculpa.

Comment: A posição absoluta em relação a todos itens dá lista?

Comment: Isso, por exemplo, o primeiro item da lista do array vai ser sempre o "0" é assim por diante, de forma que não mude de posição no adapter. Ja que Eu utilizo esse número como referência pra abrir determinadas activities

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o método `indexOf()`. Então ficaria desta forma:

```
int posicaoAbsoluta = teams.indexOf(itemValue);
```

Comment: Essa linha de código iria onde? no lv.setOnItemClickListener? e eu teria que criar uma variável para cada item? por exemplo: int posicaoAbsoluta0 = teams.indexOf(0); int posicaoAbsoluta1 = teams.indexOf(1); ..... sei que isso deve ser simples, mas sou iniciante e não sei algumas coisas direito.

Comment: @juniorklawa você vai fazer dentro do seu adapter mesmo. Em vez de colocar indexOf(0) você vai colocar o nome dá string. Ex: indexOf("América").

Answer (score 1):

Descobri a resposta, era algo bem básico. no lugar de `position` ou `itemPosition` no `Switch` deve-se colocar `itemValue` e deve-se também mudar o valor do `case` para a `String` desejada ficando desta forma:

```
switch( itemValue )
                {
                    case "Absolutismo":  Intent newActivity = new Intent(telaPesquisa.this, historiaAbsolutismo.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity);
                        break;
                    case "Agentes Formadores de Relevo":  Intent newActivityy = new Intent(telaPesquisa.this, geografiaAgentesFormadoresDeRelevo.class);
                        startActivity(newActivityy);
                        break;
                    case "Alelobiose":  Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(telaPesquisa.this, biologiaAlelobioses.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity2);
                        break;
                    case "Alta Idade Média":  Intent newActivity3 = new Intent(telaPesquisa.this, historiaAltaIdadeMedia.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity3);
                        break;
                    case "América":  Intent newActivity4 = new Intent(telaPesquisa.this, geografiaAmerica.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity4);
                        break;




                }

            }
        });
```

Obrigado a todos pela ajuda, essa comunidade tem me ajudado muito.